# how do i make an object move at a random direction on the x axis and then stay on that course?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that when spawning I want it to go either left or right randomly and stay on that course.
For example, if it decides to go left then I want it to keep going left.

so how can I do this?

I have tried using the random function but that makes it flicker back and forth.

my current code is:

```
class object {


  constructor(x, y, r) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }

  show() {
    fill(150);
    circle(this.x, this.y, this.r);
  }

  move() {
    let arr = [-1, 1]
    let xDir = random(arr[0], arr[1]);

    this.x = this.x + xDir;

  }
}
```

note: I'm a beginner and is using a beginners program called p5.js.

Comment: Decide the direction in the constructor.

Comment: thank you. Ran into another problem that it did not move at the same speed all the time but managed to solve it by creating an "if" statement that changed the speed to a whole number (-1 or 1) depending on if it was negative or positive.
if you know a better way please tell me.